# Setting column classes for different screens using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-grid

I am trying to build my UI using Bootstrap. I am trying to set 3 `divs` in one `row` next to each other for medium and large screens. And for 
under `768px` I would like to place them one under another.

**file.html**

```
<section className="about" id="about">
  <div className="container-fluid">
   <div className="row boxes justify-content-md-center">
    <div className="col-sm-12 col-md-4 box">
    <div className="innerBox">
      <div className="icons">
        <img src={iconEducation} className="img-responsive" />
      </div>
      <div className="box-body">
        <h3 className="box-title">Title </h3>

        <div className="box-list">
          <div className="box-list-items">
            <div className="item-ul"><img src={dot} className="img-responsive" /></div>
            <div>
              <p>Text</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="box-list-items">
            <div><img src={dot} className="img-responsive" /></div>
            <div className="item-ul">
              <p>Text</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

The HTML code is the same for all three `div`s.

***Problem***

On large and medium screens I have two `div`s in one row and a third underneath in new row. For tablet screens the `div`s do not flow one under another but are still in the same row. The layout I want is two in one row and the third underneath.

**file.css**

```
.about{
  padding: 127px 0 196px 0;
}

.about .row.boxes >div{
  margin: 0 20px 0 20px;
}

.about .box{
  height: 550px; 
  width: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(144deg, #fdfdfd, #f9f9f9);
}
.about .innerBox{
  margin: auto;
  color: black;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.box-list-items > div {
  display: inline-block;
}

.box-list-items img {
  height: 35%; 
  width: 35%;
}

.icons { 
  height: 95px; 
  width: 95px;
  float: right;
  margin: 7% 5% 5% 0;
}
.icons img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}


h3.box-title{
  font-size: 2.7em;
}
```

As I was going through the Bootstrap docs I thought that naming the class as `.col-md-4` would align my `div`s for above `768px` in same row one next to each other and underneath would place them in kind of `display: box` view.

Comment: You need to wrap your `col-md-4` inside a `<div class="row"></div>`

Comment: Please show a proper [mcve] that reproduces the problem. Specifying `width: 100%` for `.about .box` might interfere here.

Comment: You mean every `.col-md-4` for inside new row? Why? It should be able to have functions in one row as well. @soueuls

Comment: What is being said, is that you need to wrap your columns inside a row.

Comment: @nocturns2 but my divs are in `<div class="row"></div>`

Comment: @user9347049 When I commented it was not the case, or at least your snippet of code did not reflect it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

theres is no use of @media only screen and all ,this will work:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">abc</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4  col-md-4 col-lg-4">xyz</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4  col-md-4 col-lg-4">123</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

you can check:
https://jsfiddle.net/bfos8ttd/

Comment: @user9347049 what exactly do you want just placing them in some order the above code will do .but from your code it does seems so. use bootstrap instead

Comment: This is what I did, added bootstrap classes for all screen sizes. But problem was with my css custom added. When I fixed that it worked just fine. Thank you. :)

Comment: @user9347049 if you have accepted the answer you can give it an upvote thanks

Answer (score 1):

you need to put all the code in file.html in side a div with class row and test it again.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my code. It already there. Class `.container-fluid > .row`.

Comment: You need three box? Put another 2 within the a div and class like tat one too inside the row too, sr im on my phone so i cant type all the code

Answer (score 0):

Go to this [Link](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_basic.asp) for bootstrap columns (col-lg-4, col-md-4, col-sm-6, col-xs-12)

And follow these media query as per your device.

```
    @media only screen and (min-width:1024px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
    }

    @media only screen and (min-width:992px) and (max-width: 1023px) {

    }
    @media only screen and (min-width:768px) and (max-width: 991px) {

    }
    @media only screen and ( max-width: 767px ) {
    }
    @media only screen and ( max-width: 479px ) {
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

@user9347049 This wouldn't fit in the comments, so I'm putting it here for clarity.

Your container-fluid lets you use the entire width of the screen, but it's still just a container, that contains your rows and columns. You create rows, then, you add columns. As in:

```
<div class="container"> <!-- you can change this class to container-fluid class if you like -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can only have one container class. The row div contains all your cols divs for that row. You can have as many rows of columns as you need. If you adapt you code, you should start getting some of the results you're looking for before you look at the media query side of it.